# Scenebuilder don't work correctly under wayland

Tags: java, bash, environment-variables, scenebuilder, wayland

I notice that scenebuilder don't work correctly under session wayland. Have you a tip to make this work correctly with wayland ?
Thanx

I've add parameters in bash shell but not enough :

`export _JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1` (This setting resolves the issue of empty javadoc under Eclipse)
`export GDK_BACKEND=x11`
`export CLUTTER_BACKEND=wayland`
(cf. wiki wayland)

Comment: Please [format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.